# How to enable Rails 3 like logging in Rails 2.0.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging, ruby-on-rails-2

I have old project where I have to use `Rails 2.0.2.` I have faced problem with debugging of errors in application. Current problem is that I have very short log output in development environment:

- no SQL queries;
- no error trace;
- no params inspect;
- no response time and so on.

All I have (for each request):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/nov/2012:17:54:41 EET] "POST /products/1/nested HTTP/1.1" 500 60
- -> /products/1/nested
```

In configuration I have `log_level` enabled to `:debug` (it is enabled to :debug by default).

Any idea how I can improve logging in `Rails 2.0.2` to make it look like `Rails 2.3.x` or `3.x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log you posted is an apache (or other web server) log.  You want the log in `app/log/<environment>.log` which has all the goodies just like in Rails 2.